# doc2Vec with keras - NN achieves zero accuracy

Tags: tensorflow, keras, doc2vec

Hi I am applying an NN on tweets using doc2vec. Can anyone tell me, why my accuracy stays 0.0 in every epoch? Might the input vectors be the problem?

Sorry for asking beginners questions here. I´m not that advanced yet :-/

```
np.random.seed(seed)
model_d2v_01 = Sequential()
model_d2v_01.add(Dense(64, activation='relu', input_dim=200))
model_d2v_01.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
model_d2v_01.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss='binary_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])

model_d2v_01.fit(train_vecs_ugdbow_tgdmm, y_train,
                 validation_data=(validation_vecs_ugdbow_tgdmm, y_validation),
                 epochs=10, batch_size=32, verbose=2)
```

I´m trying to combine a DBOW and a DMM Model (Vocab).

I was following more or less this tutorial: https://github.com/tthustla/twitter_sentiment_analysis_part10/blob/master/Capstone_part10.ipynb

Comment: data source is the sentiment140 (1.6 million labeled tweets)

Comment: Input vectors might be a problem.